# Primefaces compatibility I.E 8 Message: Unexpected call to method or property access

Tags: internet-explorer, primefaces, compatibility

Seems that I.E. 8 can't allow the components of the page to be updated.

my example:

```
 <p:commandButton update="xxxxx"> dose not respond and stop all other request inside the page. what can i do?
```

The question is simply whether there is any kind of version of primefaces that works good with 
I.E 8?

My client has this browser and there is no possibility to make him change.

I'm getting crazy with compatibility problems. What kind of solution do I have?

```
Error:

Agente utente: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64;                  Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; SLCC2; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media         Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; CMDTDFJS; InfoPath.3; Tablet PC 2.0)
Timestamp: Tue, 21 Jan 2014 12:36:16 UTC


Message: Unexpected call to method or property access.
Line: 6050
Character: 5
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost:8080/caronteemir/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=4.0
```

the page is very simple: AND stop to works when i press the button

```
<p:commandButton value="submit"  <-- this button is enabled by the other button in the page there are only 2 buttons

 actionListener="#{shellManagerBean.excuteCommand()}"   <--- dose not go inside this method why ?
```

this is the whole web page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"> 
  <h:head>  
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="table-style.css" />
  </h:head> 
<h:body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document ).load(function() { 
        onclick=jQuery('#form:hdnBtn').click();
   })
 </script>  
<br/>
<div id="wrapper">
<h:form id="form">  
<h:commandButton id="hdnBtn" onclick="#{shellManagerBean.resetFilters()}" style="display: none;"/>                                    
  <p:growl id="messages" closable="true" />

       <p:dialog modal="true" widgetVar="blockPage" showHeader="false"
            resizable="false" draggable="false" id="dial"  
            style="padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:0px; padding-right:0px; padding-left:2px;">
            <div style="float: left">
                <p:graphicImage value="/resources/images/ajax-loader.gif" />
            </div>
            <div style="float: left; line-height: 32px; margin-left: 10px;">
                <h:outputText value="Loading..." />
            </div>
        </p:dialog>

     <p:panel>
        <h:form id="formh">
            <p:outputLabel   value="Host: "> </p:outputLabel>   
            <p:inputText     value="#{shellManagerBean.host}" id="host"></p:inputText>
            <p:outputLabel   value=" "> </p:outputLabel>
            <p:outputLabel   value="Pwd: "> </p:outputLabel>
            <h:inputSecret   value="#{shellManagerBean.password}" id="password" label="password" />   
            <p:outputLabel   value=" "> </p:outputLabel>
            <p:commandButton value="connect" actionListener="#{shellManagerBean.connectToHost()}" 
                             update=":form:formA:execbutton" 
                             > 
            </p:commandButton> 
            <p:outputLabel   value="     "> </p:outputLabel>

            <p:growl id="messages" closable="true" autoUpdate="true"/>

        </h:form>
     </p:panel>

     <p:panel id="shell" header="Command line shell" style="margin-bottom:10px;"> 
        <h:form id="formA"> 
        <p:inputTextarea id="resultCommand" autoResize="false" rows="35" cols="210" minQueryLength="10" value="#{shellManagerBean.textAreaValue}" />
        <br/>
        <p:commandButton value="submit" 
                         id="execbutton"
                         update="resultCommand"
                         disabled="#{shellManagerBean.disableShell}"
                         process="@form"
                         actionListener="#{shellManagerBean.excuteCommand()}"
                          />  

        <p:inputText value="#{shellManagerBean.shellCommand}" id="inputShell" label="Comando da eseguire" style="width:500px;"/>
        </h:form>    
    </p:panel>    

    </h:form>





</div>
```

Pratically the peroblem is that on any page: I press on one button this button must update other things but i do not see any change. the page does not make a partial refresh. what i must do fot it ?

Comment: I also had that problem, and the hours expending in compatibility was higher than the coding... My company uses IE7 by default, which is even worse. What i did was convince the users that Firefox/Chrome is better and faster than IE. Now my project is in date and i gained something like 20% more in production. Ohh, for your question..... I think you should talk to your client, i don't see why he doesn't want to use FF/Chrome, he can also continue using IE for his common tasks, maybe a little conversation could save you time/money...People are flexible.

Comment: :(((( really i would like this dream becomes true

Comment: Are you using some kind of css selector based on the client browser?

Comment: shit i.e. 8 SHIT SHIT IS SHIT MICROSFOT PRODUCT

Comment: calm down bro :D....have you inspected the component ID using any browser inspector to see if the ID to be updated is the same as you are trying to update?

Comment: yes id dose not exist in any other page. Pratically the peroblem is that on any page: I press on one button this button must update other things but i do not see any change. the page does not make a partial refresh. what i must do fot it ?

Comment: maybe i must use only 1 form in the page i try...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must have only 1 form in yoour page or i.e. 8 MAKES SHIT:

THANK YOU TO ALL THANK YOU TO ALL I LOVE YOU GUYS

```
<h:form id="form">

<h:commandButton id="hdnBtn" onclick="#{shellManagerBean.resetFilters()}" style="display: none;"/>


  <p:growl id="messages" closable="true" />

       <p:dialog modal="true" widgetVar="blockPage" showHeader="false"
            resizable="false" draggable="false" id="dial"  
            style="padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:0px; padding-right:0px; padding-left:2px;">
            <div style="float: left">
                <p:graphicImage value="/resources/images/ajax-loader.gif" />
            </div>
            <div style="float: left; line-height: 32px; margin-left: 10px;">
                <h:outputText value="Loading..." />
            </div>
        </p:dialog>

     <p:panel>
            <p:outputLabel   value="Host: "> </p:outputLabel>   
            <p:inputText     value="#{shellManagerBean.host}" id="host"> </p:inputText>
            <p:outputLabel   value=" "> </p:outputLabel>
            <p:outputLabel   value="Pwd: "> </p:outputLabel>
            <h:inputSecret   value="#{shellManagerBean.password}" id="password" label="password" />   
            <p:outputLabel   value=" "> </p:outputLabel>
            <p:commandButton value="connect" actionListener="#{shellManagerBean.connectToHost()}" 
                             update="execbutton" 
                             onclick="blockPage.show();" 
                             oncomplete="blockPage.hide();" > 
            </p:commandButton> 
            <p:outputLabel   value="     "> </p:outputLabel>


     </p:panel>

     <p:panel id="shell" header="Command line shell" style="margin-bottom:10px;"> 
        <p:inputTextarea id="resultCommand" autoResize="false" rows="35" cols="210" minQueryLength="10" value="#{shellManagerBean.textAreaValue}" />
        <br/>
        <p:commandButton value="Submit" 
                         id="execbutton"
                         update="resultCommand"
                         disabled="#{shellManagerBean.disableShell}"
                         process="@form"
                         actionListener="#{shellManagerBean.excuteCommand()}"
                         onclick="blockPage.show();" 
                         oncomplete="blockPage.hide();" />  

        <p:inputText value="#{shellManagerBean.shellCommand}" id="inputShell" label="Comando da eseguire" style="width:500px;"/>
    </p:panel>    

    </h:form>





</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not have a form within another form. Because when you submit the browser does not know which form corresponds

Comment: Also it's not permitted in the HTML spec: http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#the-form-element or http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#the-form-element under "Content model".

Answer (score 0):

No doubt `IE` is the worst `web browser` ever.

Try changing `Document Mode` from `Quirk` to `IE8` as in image below

[image: Changing Document Mode]

Comment: it is strange my problem seem that in other pages not makes the same

Comment: but however nice answer ;)